# VSCode Change Vertical Guide Line Indentation

Tags: visual-studio-code

I changed my VSCode settings to define a tab as 4 spaces, as opposed to the default 2 spaces. How do I make the vertical guide lines appear on every 4 spaces, as opposed to 2? Please see screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: If you have changed the setting via the [status bar](https://i.imgur.com/oKIi4e0.png) it will automatically render guidelines accordingly

Comment: Where's the status bar? How do I change a setting via the status bar?

Answer (score 8):

Open a .js file and in the status bar (at the bottom of the screen) you will find a button that says

```
Spaces: 2
```

Once you click on it, you get a menu at the top of the screen which has a button

```
change view
```

Click on it and you will be able to select the tab size for the file.

To change the setting globally, go to File -> Preferences -> Settings, search for 'tabSize' and click on Edit in settings.json. Then in the settings.json file set "editor.tabSize" to 4 and save.

Answer (score 0):

*I'm using VSCode and that's what solved the issue here*

1- create a prettier.config.js file and among the options, make sure to have these here:

```
module.exports = {
    tabWidth: 4,
    tabs: true,
    // other options...
}
```

2- Open the options bar (<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>) and select "Developer: Reload window" to reload the IDE.